# Cloned system partition on the same hdd, how to make it bootable? W7

Tags: windows-7, clone, clonezilla, boot-partition

Well, system partition was about 30Gb and now its running low, so i cloned the system partition in the same hdd and gave this partition a way more space, so i dont have this kind of problem again. But the question is, how to make the new cloned partition bootable, and can i delete the old system partition after that?
I have one hdd with 1TB, and windows 7 is on the usb drive.

Comment: If you have windows7 installtion media still, boot from that, then choose repair and launch CMD and enter the following commands: 
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /RebuildBcd

Answer (score 0):

If it's clone by clonezilla (which should use ntfsclone from ntfs-3g), then the boot sector of the cloned partition is probably not something you need to worry (i.e. it is cloned bootable).

You probably just need to modify the BCD with `bcdedit` to point the bootloader to cloned partition: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

If it's a BIOS/MBR installation, you probably need to mark the cloned partition as active with `diskpart` as well

Answer (score -2):

You can use the windows recovery options from your windows install disk to identify existing windows partitions and repair the boot record.

Use the boot recovery options Bootrec as [described here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-7-recovery-environment-command-prompt/)

Comment: How provide specific instructions how it is used.